# How to calculate the voltage divider resistor for transistor?

Tags: analog

How do I calculate the voltage divider resistors (R1 & R2?)

I have found that the relay resistance is 1150 ohm.

[image]

Ic = 20.8 mA, hfe = 290, Ib = 71 µA.

I'm using a BC847b transistor.  The voltage divider network acts as a switch to turn on the 1CO relay.

Comment: provide a schematic? and how about protecting against inductive kick, that will destroy the transistor when quickly turned off?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the transistor as a low speed switch, not as a linear amplifier. This makes things much simpler because you don't need to control the bias voltage then. The transistor is always driven into saturation, which is actually good because it limits the power dissipated inside the transistor to very low values. No heatsink required.

Drop R2 completely. Make R1=2.2kΩ, which gives you a reasonable saturated base current of about 2mA. The collector current is limited by the solenoid resistance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use voltage divider there. The resistance that base sees is R1||R2 (they are parallel according to base).

It is a basic switching circuit. Simply, the idea is to make the Hfe*Ib bigger than expected collector current to keep it in the saturated region to keep the colector voltage as low as possible.

Simple but not without some glitches. Hfe changes with temperature and also Ic. You have to study the datasheet to find a safe value that being a compromise between lower base current and safer operating point.